# How to Customize the EventPlus Plugin in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using Event Plus Plugin Which I Purchased. Using EventPlus Plugin I

used the shortcode then generate the event which is showing on the calendar When

I click on the Particular event Which is showing on the calendar working Properly.

I want to pass date of calendar into url which is going to the Event page When I

click. I don't know which file is using and where I can customise the file

Answer (score 0):

There is a slug option in Wordpress, The “slug” is the URL-friendly version of the name. It is usually all lowercase and contains only letters, numbers, and hyphens.

[image: Slug]

You can change your URL here as per you need while assigning your Event Categories itself.